# Python: separating strings using pipes as delimiter

Tags: python, string, split, delimiter

I have a list of strings with data separated by pipes, I want to split these strings using pipes as the delimiter. I have tried using x.split('|'), however it is not working. here is my current code:

```
 datas = []
    location = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    with open(filename, newline = '') as dar:
        for row in csv.reader(dar):
            datas.append(row)
    for x in datas:
       x[0].split('|')
```

and this is a snippet of the output I'm getting:

```
['Crimson Rosella|-35.27454538728105|149.11596655088428|ACTON|2004-02-01|Aves|Psittaciformes|Psittacidae|Platycercus|Platycercus elegans|False'], ['Little cormorant|-35.27719826516971|149.11525904557516|Australian National University|2015-06-13|Aves|Pelecaniformes|Phalacrocoracidae|Phalacrocorax|Phalacrocorax melanoleucos|False']
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `delimiter` parameter in csv module to separate by `|`

**Ex:**

```
import csv
with open(filename) as dar:
    for row in csv.reader(dar, delimiter='|'):
        print(row)
```

**Output:**

```
['Crimson Rosella', '-35.27454538728105', '149.11596655088428', 'ACTON', '2004-02-01', 'Aves', 'Psittaciformes', 'Psittacidae', 'Platycercus', 'Platycercus elegans', 'False']
['Little cormorant', '-35.27719826516971', '149.11525904557516', 'Australian National University', '2015-06-13', 'Aves', 'Pelecaniformes', 'Phalacrocoracidae', 'Phalacrocorax', 'Phalacrocorax melanoleucos', 'False']
```

Answer (score 0):

`x[0].split('|')` doesn't achieve anything since you do not do anything with  its result. Maybe you want to do this instead?

```
datas = [x.split('|') for x in datas]
```

and you can probably do it all in one go with this instead too:

```
datas.append(row.split('|'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
# x = text from line in datas, x[0] = first letter on the line
x = "Crimson Rosella|-35.27454538728105|149.11596655088428|ACTON|2004-02-01|Aves|Psittaciformes|Psittacidae|Platycercus|Platycercus elegans|False'], ['Little cormorant|-35.27719826516971|149.11525904557516|Australian National University|2015-06-13|Aves|Pelecaniformes|Phalacrocoracidae|Phalacrocorax|Phalacrocorax melanoleucos|False"

x = x.split('|')

print(x)
```